# Creating List of Pair type (Value,Value) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I would like to create pair of list of some int values like

> (3,4) , (5,4) ,(5,1)....(n,n)

then match each with single target like

> (1,1)

I need to compare each value of list with target **(1,1)** , so that it should print the most nearest point to **(1,1)**

**Expected Result.**

> (3,4)

**What is Nearest**

Nearest means , lets say if we have number 4,5,6,7,8 and I want to find most nearest number to 12 so answer will be 8 because it takes 4 to reach 12 but 4+n moves to reach 12 from other, so in same way unlike single value I have pair of values (n,n).... and compare with (n,n)

**What I Have Tried Using 2D Array**

```
positions = new int[3][,] 
{
new int[,] { {3,4} },
new int[,]{ {5,4}},
 new int[,] { {5,1} }

};
```

This gives me

> 3,4
>
> 5,4
>
> 5,1

Now I need to compare each value with (1,1) but I dont know any proper data structure through which I can easily store my list and compare each with (1,1).

Please help

Comment: what is "compare each value with `(1,1)` "? Does `(5,1)` match of only `(1,1)`?

Comment: no I have to just find smallest point to 1,1 so first 3,4 compare with 1,1 and set 3,4 as smallest than compare with 5,4 and so on ...so in the end most nearest point will be 3,4

Comment: What does "nearest" mean? Are you only comparing the first numbers?

Comment: please review question , i have update the definition of nearest in this context

Comment: how is nearest not (5,1)?

Comment: Is your expected result really `(3, 4)`? Because the distance of `(3, 4)` from `(1, 1)` is `3 - 1 + 4 - 1 = 2 + 3 = 5` and the distance between `(5, 1)` and `(1, 1)` is `5 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 4 + 0 = 4`

Comment: In euclidean distance I believe (3,4) would be closer to (1,1) then (5,1). Though the talk about "moves" could imply manhattan distance...it's not very clear^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that these points are points in a plane and we can use [Pythagorean theorem](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section01.02.html) to get the distance between two points.

With that assumption out of the way, I would create a new class to hold the x/y positional data and a `DistanceBetween` method which runs the `Pythagorean theorem`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(3, 4),
        new Point(5, 4),
        new Point(5, 1)
    };

    Point closestPoint = points.OrderBy(point => point.DistanceFromPoint(new Point(1, 1))).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine($"The closest point to 1,1 is {closestPoint.PosX},{closestPoint.PosY}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private class Point
{
    public Point(int posX, int posY)
    {
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = posY;
    }

    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }

    public double DistanceFromPoint(Point otherPoint)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((otherPoint.PosX - PosX), 2) + Math.Pow((otherPoint.PosY - PosY), 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is also good (I was doubting between "own" class and Tuple)

Comment: as i went under the assumption they're geometric points, felt easier to encompass the formula in a method than having it in the linq :). But yours totally does the job as well

Answer (score 6):

C# 7 has tuples and I think you're looking for that!

E.g. a list of tuples:

```cs
var positions = new List<(int x, int y)>
{
    (3,4),
    (5,4),
    (5,1)
};
```

You could find the "closest" for example like this:

```
(int x, int y) value = (1, 1);
var closest = positions.OrderBy(p => (p.x - value.x) + (p.y - value.y)).First(); // finds (5,1)
```